# Connect to mongoDb Bitnami server hosted on Amazon EC2

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

So I have written a basic program with PHP and MongoDB and I tested it locally using xampp. This all works fine. Now I want to publish it as a website.

After some research I decided to use Bitnami and I am running an EC2 server on Amazon. I am able to ssh and run commands from the terminal. Now I want to connect to the server and create a Mongo client. I am a bit puzzled and do not know how to do this exactly. I am using the code below. The ssh works fine but I do not know how to set up the mongo client. The '$m = new MongoClient();' works fine locally for localhost, I have also tried to supply to MongoClient my username and password but without success. Thank you very much for any help!

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('../../etc/bitnami.pem'));


$ssh = new Net_SSH2('ip_address');
if (!$ssh->login('bitnami', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$ssh->exec('mongo admin --username root -p <myPassword>');

$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->mydb;
echo "Database mydb selected";
$collection = $db->mycol;
echo "Collection selected succsessfully";

$document = array( 
   "title" => "MongoDB", 
   "description" => "database"
);

$collection->insert($document);
```

---

Update answer to Jota Martos (unable to write it as comment):
Hi, thank you for your answer. Yes for now I allow access from all ports and IP's for test purposes. I can successfully connect via ssh but now I am stuck. I am running a Mean bitnami application and my website is running on GoDaddy server under PHP. So I want to connect with PHP to my mongoDB bitnami app that is hosted on AWS. So now the problem is that on my GoDaddy server mongoDB is not installed. So running the following code does not work:

```
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://${bitnami}:${AWSpassword}@hostIp");
```

Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found.

So my question how do I connect with PHP from my GoDaddy server to the EC2 Amazon server and connect to Bitnami mongoDB account. Should I first setup an ssh connection to the server and then try to login to mongoDB server or how should I connect?

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to php.net the function that is used is Deprecated, [refer this](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php).

Can you try something like:

```
<?php

$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://myusername:myp%40ss%3Aw%25rd@example.com/mydatabase");

?>
```

[Refer this](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look into that. What I do not understand is that for my EC2 server I have an IP,user and password, and then on server the mongoDB app is running with user and password. Should I first ssh to my server and then try to create a MongoDB connection using this command?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bitnami Engineer here,

Apart from this [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46691826/4709625), please note that the database port for the nodes in this solution cannot be accessed over a public IP address by default. For security reasons, we do not recommend making the database port accessible over a public IP address.

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/mongodb/#how-to-connect-to-mongodb-from-a-different-machine

You can open the MongoDB port in the server by accessing the AWS console and modifying the access group configuration

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/#how-to-open-the-server-ports-for-remote-access

You will also need to modify the MongoDB configuration file (`/opt/bitnami/mongodb/mongodb.conf`) to allow the database to not to work only on 127.0.0.1.

Regards,
Jota

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes for now I opened all ports for testing purposes. However, what I do not understand is how can I connect from my external server to my EC2 server and run mongoDB. Because on my external server MongoDB is not installed and I can not use the PHP command "new MongoDB\Driver\Manager". I can ssh using PHP to my EC2 instance but then how do I connect to mongoDB? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You will only need to use the MongoDB driver for PHP in your script, you don't need to create a SSH tunnel if you opened the ports or installing the MongoDB client in the server. You will find more information about how to install and use that driver in the its official PHP page: http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

Comment: Thank you! So I was able to enable the Mongo PHP driver on the server. I enabled traffic UDP/TCP on IC2 and changed bind_ip to 0.0.0.0 . I checked on IC2 and mongoDB instance is up and running. However, I get the following error message “Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: ip:port: Connection refused”.I am using following command “$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://ip",array("username"=>"bitnami","password"=> $key));”I know that this call is deprecated but the other command does not generate error message.Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Hi, did you check the MongoDB configuration file? As I mentioned, we configured MongoDB to not to accept remote connections so in case you want to open the ports, you also need to modify the bind_ip setting in [the mongodb.conf file](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/mongodb/#mongodb-configuration-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to connect a tool like Studio 3T to a remote Mongodb instance built using bitnami AMI you can follow the steps below:

1. Open inbound port 27017 on instance security group.

2. Open Instance log of the instance and find the password for user root.

3. Open Studio 3T, server name is instance public ip and port 27017.

4. Got to Authentication and select basic and put in the user as root and password as obtained from instance log.

Click on Test Connection, it should work.